# Autocorrelation of Brownian motion - question about derivation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The calculation of the autocorrelation function for particles undergoing Brownian motion is described in chapter 7.6 of Chaikin and Lubensky (See picture below). There are couple of things which I dont understand here.

The derivation begins defining $P(x,t|x_0,t_0)=\left<\delta(x-x(t))_{x_0,t_0}\right>$ where the averaging is over the random force, and $x_0,t_0$ are the initial condition of the particles. The equation 7.4.37 is the autocorrelation function when sme number of particles diffuse via Brownian motion.

1. The general expression for the transition amplitude in equation 7.4.38 isn't clear to me. I understand that $P(x,t|x',t')$ should somehow be a some over $x_0,t_0$ for the probabilities to go $P(x',t'|x_0,t_0)P(x,t|x_0,t_0)$ but this shuold give $\left<\delta(\dots)\right>\left<\delta(\dots)\right>$ and not $\left<\delta(\dots)\delta(\dots)\right>$.
2. Why $\left< \delta(x'-x(t')) \right>$ is unifrom? I assume this quantity is just the probability $P(x,t)$ to be at a certain place at a certain time? Is it necessary to assume a finite space?
3. What is the difference between the self-correlation $S_{self}$ and the density correlation function? The density is simply $n(x,t)=\sum_\alpha \delta(x-x(t))$ so shouldn't $\left< n(x,t) n(x',t') \right>$ be the same as 7.4.37?

[image]